# Rails allowing null when should not allow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :code
      t.integer :gtin
      t.references :supplier, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :group, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I create table products, the above migration was created. But I dont want to name and code should accept null. So I created a new migration like this:

```
class ChangeNameAndCodeToNotNullInProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    change_column :products, :name, :string, null: false
    change_column :products, :code, :string, null: false
  end
end
```

But when I go in products form and click on create. It still accepts to create with all data in blank. What do I missing?

Comment: empty strings are not nulls -- odds are good your database has empty strings in those columns.  Check out the atrribute normalizer https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer if you are using a Rails version < 7.1

Comment: It's also possible that, if you are using a MySQL database, that you have strict mode disabled.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: If you want to consider empty strings as null, then use `.presence` to reduce them to `nil` before saving.

Comment: Did you check via the Rails console or through a DB client what is the actual value saved in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me one time, you should restart rails server and/or console after appplying the migration, it should honor the not null after that